# write all backbone model attributes to html template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

I am using a backbone view to write out model data to a template.

I am currently doing this in the view:

```
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        className: 'presentationListItem',
        template: _.template(tmpl, null, { variable: 'm' }),

        render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(_.extend({}, this.model.toJSON())));
        return this;
}
```

And then in my HTML template, I access the data like this:

```
Catalog ID: {{ m.Id }} <br />
Catalog Name: {{ m.Name }} <br />
```

Lately, I've been having to pass different models through this view with different attributes.

I was wondering if there's a way to just write out everything in the model to the HTML template without having to specify specific attributes(ie ctx.Id, ctx.Name) like I'm doing now.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how you can do this without having a dynamic template. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass multiply models to the view you can do it like this:

Inside you view:

```
template: _.template(tmpl)
...

render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template({
           model1: this.model1.toJSON(),
           model2: this.model2.toJSON()}));
        return this;
}
```

And your template:

```
Catalog ID: {{ model1.Id }} <br />
Catalog Name: {{ model2.Id }} <br />
```

Comment: Thanks! But I meant that I won't always know the names of the attributes. So basically, I'd just like to dump all the attributes into the template.

Answer (score 1):

You could use _.values(object) - http://underscorejs.org/#values

This would return all the values for that object's properties.

You might be better, however, using different views for your different model types and having tailored templates for each one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to see everything inside model, you can make nice readable string from json by passing parameters to [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and then print it somewhere in view.

```
JSON.stringify(this.model.toJSON(), false, 2)
```